# menu li active mouse event add span style

Tags: javascript, html

I can print active when any url is clicked from the event menu I want to do. I want to give a style to "menu_item_line" span for the activated a href. but I did not do well. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
<div class="middle_right right header_side">
    <div class="header_side_container">
        <div class="header_builder_component header_builder_menu_component">
            <nav class="main-menu main_menu_container menu_line_enable">
                <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1032">
                        <a href="home.php"><span>Home</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1033">
                        <a href="videos.php"><span>videos</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1034">
                        <a href="gallery.php">
                            <span>gallery</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1035">
                        <a href="about.php">
                            <span>about</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1036">
                        <a href="contact.php">
                            <span>contact</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    **<span class="menu_item_line"></span>**
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**li active**

```
function updateMenu(url) {
    const active = document.querySelector('.menu-item.active');

    if (active !== null) {
        active.classList.remove('active');
    }

    const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item'));

    links.forEach(function (li) {
        let anchor = li.querySelector("a");
        if (url.indexOf(anchor.href) > -1) {
            li.classList.add("active");
        }
    });
}

updateMenu(window.location.href);
```